# User input possibilities of pairs to match to arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance, time

I am trying to find the most efficient way, in javascript(I'm using node.js), of taking a user's input and pairing the inputs to find exact array matches. I know how to do this without performance in mind, my main goal is the best performance algorithm.

For example:
User input(can have up to 15 animals): `dog bear cat lion snake`

The api data(in json), where the animal array length is always 2:

```json
{
  data: [
   { animals: ["cat", "dog"], content: "demo content 1." },
   { animals: ["snake", "cat"], content: "demo content 2." },
   { animals: ["bird", "mouse"], content: "demo content 3." }
  ]
}
```

I want to find all the animal matches, in this case, the user input would match to `dog cat` `cat snake` animals. I would be able to access "demo content 1." and "demo content 2.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly efficient method would be to use `Array.reduce` on the `data` array, checking that each value in `data.animals` is in the user input and if so, pushing the content to the output:

```js
const apidata = {
  data: [
   { animals: ["cat", "dog"], content: "demo content 1." },
   { animals: ["snake", "cat"], content: "demo content 2." },
   { animals: ["bird", "mouse"], content: "demo content 3." }
  ]
}

const userinput = ['dog', 'bear', 'cat', 'lion', 'snake']

const content = apidata.data.reduce((c, o) => {
  if (o.animals.every(a => userinput.includes(a)))
    c.push(o.content);
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(content)
```